# show Both placeholder with text in UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

i want to show  User's Text input with PlaceHolder ,so  When the user enter text, they can still see the title of the field. this is the same Functionality on iphone About us Page [image: please see the image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: clear question pls? nice image.

Comment: You want to see the name of the placeHolder after enter the text, don't you?

Comment: Don't you think it will look messy due to overlapping?

Comment: as @RoxeeMan suggested you can use two separate control for display and input with this you can solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should have a `UILabel` as `Placeholder` at the left of the `cell`, and the `UITextField` at right.

If you want to edit your `textField` wherever you touch the cell. use `[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];` in  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method